# Self storage space rental software

Tags: reservation

You know those places where you rent storage space by the month? A friend of a friend has one & is looking for some software to run it, as things are done on paper at the moment.

- Any o/s
- preferably gratis, but sub $1k *might* be acceptable
- calendar based reservation system
- customer management
- invoicing

That's about the basics, as far as I understand it (he is on a another continent and there is a language barrier).

It might also be nice if the system can write mag swipe cards or RFID/NFC tags to open the main door (and record who opens it) outside of business hours.

That's about as specific as I have it now, but I can relay your questions, if any, and update this question with any answer received.

Feel free to change the tag.

Comment: It would maybe better if he asked the question himself, wouldn't it? - I think you should be looking for two softwares. One for the invoicing etc. (I have heard good things about GnuCash for that) the other one for the resource calendar. Maybe you find one that can combine them. As soon as you enter the "write mag swipe cards" area you will most likely leave the gratis part and sub $1k will most likely not get the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Booked Scheduler

As usual for resource scheduling software, I recommend [Booked Scheduler](https://www.bookedscheduler.com/). It's the most sophisticated free and open source software for resource scheduling that I know of.

It can manage user accounts and allows extra fields to be added to user records (so-called "user defined attributes"). For example, address information fields etc. – so that would be your "customer management".

The software includes direct payment integration (Stripe and PayPal) since the latest release (see the [release announcement](https://nickkorbel.com/2018/05/03/booked-2-7-is-out-in-beta/)).

You would have to add the missing pieces via third-party applications that you would connect to the API of Booked Scheduler:

- invoice generation from the usage data and user profile data stored in Booked Scheduler
- RFID / NFC access management functions for the users stored in the Booked Scheduler database

### Alternatives

For a list of all the other open source resource booking and scheduling applications that I could find, see [this detailed list](https://edgeryders.eu/t/6629). I still think Booked Scheduler would be the way to go, but you might find something else that suits you.

Comment: A great answer to a very old question. I wish that I could upvote you more, for the additional list.

Comment: Btw, maybe you could help with https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/54838/software-for-school-management-child-care#comment76677_54838 ? It's sort of related

Comment: Now it offers trial in the website, guess it moved to paid version?

Comment: @Dane411 Yes, Booked Scheduler has been commercialized. But the open source version is being continued by a different team. Details and links in my analysis at https://edgeryders.eu/t/6629

Answer (score 1):

Please find below the software who can fit with your all needs for self storage business.
[ManageStorageUnits](https://www.managestorageunits.com/)

It has all features like calendar based reservation system, customer management, invoicing.