# Software for school management (child care) where parents are charged by hour

Tags: open-source, php, wordpress, cloud-service

I am looking for help to find open source cloud-hosted solution for child care where I would need all the student info, notifications... but I need to be able to input how many hours a week was a kid in childcare and then output price for it to a parent.

I need something that gives option to charge parents not by semester or class (as it is done in schools) but by hour (since it is used for child care).

Comment: Why not use one of those that you suggest? And, whatever you do, make sure that the data are encrypted, not plain-text, lest you be hacked.

Comment: @Mawg Because neither of them supports hourly fees.

Comment: @Mawg it's 2019 and obviously, everyone is going to log in to use it. There are different permission groups as default on every software. Servers get secured with firewall, the database is encrypted, traffic is transmitted with ssl encryption.
I don't need a lesson on security but a software recommendation, please.

Comment: "*where I would need all the student info*" <- is it a typo? Did you mean "input" instead of "need"?

Comment: That's good to know (+1). I hope that you get your answer. I imagine that you already checked SourceForge & GitHub. If you don't get an answer, try to think of things with similar functionality. Good luck.

Comment: Please remove the mentions of EduSec/SchoolPress and instead explain in detail all of the features you need. The second paragraph is a good start. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul  I have put EduSec/SchoolPress as a starting ground since they seem as very good software, however in my specific use case scenario I need something that also gives option to charge parents not by semester or class (as it is done in schools) but by hour (since it is used for child care).

Comment: A commercial vendor of a day-care ERP software would just add the feature that is required. Otherwise, run a virtual time-clock software separate from an accounting and billing software. Then manually input the weekly hour totals into the billing software.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but a simple way to do this is as follows:

- Use a simple timetracker like [Kimai v2](https://github.com/kevinpapst/kimai2)
- Create a "Customer" named after the nursery or childcare provider e.g. "All Day Nursery"
- Create Parents as "Projects" by creating a Project for each one  against this "Customer". You can use parent names or any ID Number. Hence no child details are entered e.g. "Mr X", "Mrs Y", "Parent 12345" etc.
- Create an Activity "Childcare" that is not attached to any Project.
- Now enter time for any child using parent name or Id (e.g. Mr X) against the "Childcare" Activity. In Kimai, it allows a Fixed rate or Hourly rate to be entered at this level. So choose the hourly rate and enter the rate.
- Hence when timesheet report for a particular parent (project) is shown, it gives hourly totals in currency setup for the project.